# Unable to start free trial and adding billing account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have create a new GCP account with organization. Now I am trying to get $300 free trial. I fill my credit card details in the below, the amount gets deducted and I again land on the below page. I tried this 3 time and nothing is happening, only amount gets deducted from my credit card.

[image]

Any Idea why is it happening?

I have created organisation in my previous accounts also with no issue. This is the first time I am facing this issue.

Comment: Rather ask the support.

Comment: I am not sure how to take support when there is no billing account. Let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: Do you have an existing organization? Consider creating an independent project and billing account which will receive the credits. Then create an organization or import the project into an existing organization. Note: if you previously received credits, you won't receive more.

Comment: i purchased a new domain name and configured it as organization in GCP. The organisation is now appearing in my account. Now when I try to create billing account, the amount get deducted from the credit card, but the above said page keep on appearing and there is no confirmation that my billing account is created.

Comment: Looks like there is a bug in GCP because of which I am not able to create a billing account. Not sure how to connect with google to get support when there is no active billing account.

Comment: I was facing the same issue too :(

Comment: Have you used this credit card with GCP before?

Comment: I have tried both used and unused Credit Card.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it needs to be directed to support

Answer (score 1):

*Google Cloud Engineers are aware about this issue*.

Please follow [this issue report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186210363) at the Google Public Issue Tracker to be updated. Feel free to add comments, CC yourself to receive emails with updates and press `+1`.